# Sort objects in Rails index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, controller, indexing

Is there any way to order a list of items through the controller in rails in **index** ?

Something like

```
def index
  @items = Item.all(order_by :date)
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course there is, and in fact, it's exactly what you said, except your method calls are off.

```
def index
    @items = Item.order(:date)
end
```

Your index view (probably index.html.erb) is looking for an `@items` array, right? Well you can format/order/etc that data however you see fit,no problem!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
@items = Item.all
@items.sort! { |a,b| a.date <=> b.date }
```

There is another method supported by Ruby:

```
@items = Item.all.sort_by &:date
```